# Symfony2 phpCAS and SAML

Tags: symfony, saml, cas

I am new to Symfony2 framework and I need to use phpCAS to connect to the CAS server of the company. They are using SAML to validate the tickets.

I tried to use BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle in order to log in the CAS server. It worked well until it failed to validate my ticket because it does not support SAML validation as far as I understand it.

So I found this https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Symfony+CAS+Client and I would like to know if this is possible to use it with Symfony 2.3 or if it will not work at all.

Thank you guys

Comment: That code will not work with Symfony2. There are still [no good bundles for integrating CAS with Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639504/cas-authentication-symfony2).